# Why my function print every dataframe in R?

Tags: r

first question here,

I use `function()` and I trigger it with `by()`. However, it always printing my dataframe.

Here's my code :

```
my_func <- function(Slice){
  a <- nrow(Slice)
  b <- nrow(Slice[!is.na(Slice$Désinscription),])
  if(a!=b){
    Camp3 <<- rbind(Camp3, Slice)
  }
}
by(Camp2,Camp2$Type, my_func)
```

Here is what my last console lines looks like (max.print=10) :
[My console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLqZa.png)

It's the same head of my data frame. However, because I add data, the length is growing up. That shows something print everytime my function is activated.

is it the `by()` function that create this ?

Here's a working example with `iris`

```
my_func <- function(x){
}
by(iris,iris$Species, my_func)
```

I expect that my console don't print every time my dataframe is use

Comment: `by()` will print the results to the console if they are not saved to an object. If you did: `out <- by(iris,iris$Species, my_func)`, you would see the output show up in the object `out` not on the console.  Also, I would also humbly suggest finding another way to do what you want than `<<-`.  In this case, I doubt it will do what you want.  In your case, the object `Camp3` will be saved only for the last value of `Type`.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong `<<-` does in place replacement. Thus it will modify the `Camp3` variable wherever it is on the stack. I guess OP defined it in the Global environment, hence he will have the results. But you are right that one should avoid at all cost the use of `<<-` unless otherwise.

Comment: Seems you want to rbind the results. Just do `if(a!=b) Slice`. Then run `do.call(rbind, by(Camp2,Camp2$Type, my_func))` no need of defining `Camp3` or doing multiple row binding

Comment: Thanks @DaveArmstrong. The `<<-` seems necessery to use `rbind()` in `function()`. I use `out <- by()` and my problem was solved.

Comment: @Onyambu, your trick worked to remove `<<-` I'll look further for `do.call()`. Thanks